# Accommodation, sights and food in Maui

Tags: accommodation, food-and-drink, sightseeing, hawaii

I just booked a flight for Maui from 20th October to 7th of November.

I am interested in hearing tips related to Maui. I know I can grab Lonely Planet for that, but first I'd like to hear some first hand information. I am after what to do, what not to do, what to visit, what to avoid, and also some more specific questions such as:

1. Where do you suggest living in the area of Lahaina? I am going with three other friends. Hotels seems kind of expensive so I think the best way for us would be to rent an apartment - any suggestions about this? Anyone happens to know a safe site to book/view an apartment/house
2. Which places to visit? I would mainly like to see some natural beauties (parks, beaches, ..)
3. Where to eat? I am looking for places in which I could get the best ratio for quality/price.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Travel.SE.  If you take a look at the FAQ, we try to keep away from questions that don't have one definite answer and that ask for discussions.  I came in to close it, but your specific questions are more useful than the title, so I'm renaming the question and suggest rephrasing some of them to be more definite.  Also retagged to maui and hawaii, as you had central-america as a tag, hope that's ok!  Saying that, other mods may still wish to rephrase it further or request more specific questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maui is great for the first time Hawaii traveler, and gives a good dose of the adventure - the gorgeous scenery along with the famed hospitality, and staying for a few days, as you are, will serve you well. Lahaina is a good location to explore the island, plus it is relatively economical compared to Kapalua and the pricey Wailea. It also has a ton of economical eateries and night life along the main strip. We specifically stayed at the [Hyatt](http://maui.hyatt.com/) - loved it, though it was a bit expensive. 
Make sure you rent a car, as you will need one to explore the island.

Must-Do List -

1. The Drive to Hana - culminating in a trek through the bamboo forest leading to the waterfall. The journey is the destination!
2. Eat at the Royal Hawaiian Luau - a bit touristy. Hawaiian food, in my opinion, is bland, but the show is interesting and gives you something to write home about.
3. Sunrise at Haleakala - Seeing the sun ascend above the hills amidst the clouds is surreal. They have biking tours on the way down. Also carry blankets/jackets, as it does get **really** cold!
4. Helicopter over Molokai Sea Cliffs - if you are of the daring type, try the [doors-off](http://www.helitour.com/tours.html) tour
5. Snorkel to Molokini - Plenty of operators, and most provide lunch on board the vessel.
6. Beaches! Go over to the Big beach past Wailea, Kapalua (a bit windy), and all the red/black/white/brown sanded ones along the ride to Hana - absolutely stunning!

A tip to save money - Some of the tours can get really expensive. Since you are there for an extended time, consider signing up for some timeshare presentations (though they mostly market to couples). You will have to spare 2-3 hours hearing some salesman trying convince you to spend $25,000 (lol!) on something you'll probably not use - but, in turn, they will offer you SIGNIFICANT discounts (may be even free!) on the excursions. Our helicopter tour was regularly priced at $189, and we only paid $69.

Answer (score 3):

If you like magic, this is an awesome show: [Warren and Annabelle's.](http://www.warrenandannabelles.com/)